# Android | Intent not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I am learning Android basics course in Udacity. As my intent didn't work properly, I tried fiddling with the code to correct in a few places and changed it. After trying to modify it, the code is neither working in intent nor in a normal way. I had to take a break in between and lost track of the changes which are done. Now I'm stuck and clueless about what has gone wrong.

Could someone go through it and guide me clearly how to fix this?

XML code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText

        android:id="@+id/Name_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textCapWords" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="toppings"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/whipped_cream_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:text="Whipped cream"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chocolate_Checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:text="Chocolate"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:onClick="decrement"
            android:text="-" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:onClick="increment"
            android:text="+" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="submitOrder"
        android:text="Order"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/price_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Java code:

```
/**
* Add your package below. Package name can be found in the project's AndroidManifest.xml file.
* This is the package name our example uses:
*/
package com.example.adom.justjava;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

import static android.R.id.edit;
import static android.R.id.message;

/**
* This app displays an order form to order coffee.
*/
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int quantity = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the increment button is clicked.
     */
    public void increment(View view) {
           if (quantity ==100){
               //Show an error message when more than 100 is pressed
               Toast.makeText(this,"You cannot have more than 100 coffees", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return ;
        }
        quantity = quantity + 1;
        displayQuantity(quantity);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the decrement button is clicked.
     */
    public void decrement(View view) {
        if (quantity==1){
            //Show an error message if user is trying to order less than a coffee
            Toast.makeText(this,"You cannot have less than 1 coffee", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return ;
        }
        quantity = quantity - 1;
        displayQuantity(quantity);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
     */
    public void submitOrder(View view) {

        //Finds the Name of the user
        EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name_field) ;
        String name = nameField.getText().toString() ;

        //Figure out if the user wants whippedcream topping
        CheckBox whippedCreamCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.whipped_cream_checkbox);
        boolean hasWhippedCream = whippedCreamCheckBox.isChecked();

        //Figure out if the user wants Chocolate topping
        CheckBox chocolateCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chocolate_Checkbox) ;
        boolean hasChocolate = chocolateCheckBox.isChecked();

        /**
         * Calculates the price of the order.
        */
        int price = calculatePrice(hasWhippedCream, hasChocolate);
         /**
         * Displays the price Message of the order.
         */
        String priceMessage = createOrderSummary(price, hasWhippedCream, hasChocolate, name);

        //Sends an email of order summary after calculating the order value
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mail to:"));
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Just Java Order for" + name);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, priceMessage);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null) {
                startActivity(intent); }
        }

    /**
     * Calculates the price of the order
     */
    private int calculatePrice(boolean hasWhippedCream, boolean hasChocolate) {
       //Price of 1 cup of Coffee
        int basePrice = 5;

        // Add $1 if the user wants 1 cup of coffee
        if (hasWhippedCream)  {
            basePrice += 1; }

        //Add $2 if the user wants 2 cups of coffee
        if(hasChocolate) {
            basePrice += 2;
            }
        //Calculate the Total order priceby multiplying by quantity
        return quantity*basePrice ;
    }

    /**
     * Create summary of the order.
     *
     * @param hasWhippedCream is whether or not the user wants whipped cream topping
     * @param hasChocolate is whether or not the user wants whipped cream topping
     * @param price of the order
     * @return text summary
     * @param name : Name field entry
     */
    private String createOrderSummary(int price, boolean hasWhippedCream, boolean hasChocolate, String name) {
        String priceMessage = "Name: " + name ;
        priceMessage += "\n Add Whipped Cream ? " + hasWhippedCream ;
        priceMessage += "\n Add Chocolate ? " + hasChocolate ;
        priceMessage = priceMessage + "\n Quantity :" + quantity ;
        priceMessage = priceMessage + "\n Total: " + price ;
        priceMessage = priceMessage + "\n Thank you!";
        return priceMessage ;
    }
    /**
     * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
     */
    private void displayQuantity(int number) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
    }
    private void displayMessage(String message) {
        TextView PriceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_text_view);
        PriceTextView.setText(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is space in `mail to`. I think it should be `mailto`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change intent call as following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/html");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "emailaddress@emailaddress.com");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Just Java Order for" + name);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, priceMessage);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

Also it is a good programming practice to keep your code clean by adding view declarations after class signature and before onCreate(), like following :

```
private EditText etEdittext;
private TextView txtQuantity;
```

and declare it in onCreate() method as following :

```
txtQuantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
```

Try to declare methods private if you are using within a same class.

Comment: Thanks archana..!! what is createchooser used for ??

Comment: Following like will help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653725/why-use-intent-createchooser

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "emailaddress@emailaddress.com");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm email body.");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

The above code you should be help to open intent.

Answer (score 0):

You have written all functionality in methods and not calling them anywhere. In `onCreate` call the specific function on views click according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

just change your "mail to" to "mailto" that's enough

Comment: otherwise do this, it worked for me hope it will work for you too :
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
     "mailto","you@gmail.com", null));
     emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test");
     emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Testing mail"); startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made any call to the displayMessage method because of which your TextView isn't displaying anything. You can add the second line to your code.

```
String priceMessage = createOrderSummary(price, hasWhippedCream, hasChocolate, name);
displayMessage(priceMessage);
```

You can call an intent to send email using the following

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Just Java Order for" + name);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , priceMessage);
try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail"));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(CoffeeClass.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: HI, I tried calling displayMessage(priceMessage); method, but that didn't work. It shows an error saying missing method body or abstract / Cannot resolve symbol priceMessage..!!

Answer (score 0):

Need to set Intent type `"plain/text"` and modify your `email` sending `Intent` extras.

**Update your `submitOrder()` method as below:**

```
/**
 * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
 */
public void submitOrder(View view) {

    //Finds the Name of the user
    EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name_field) ;
    String name = nameField.getText().toString() ;

    //Figure out if the user wants whippedcream topping
    CheckBox whippedCreamCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.whipped_cream_checkbox);
    boolean hasWhippedCream = whippedCreamCheckBox.isChecked();

    //Figure out if the user wants Chocolate topping
    CheckBox chocolateCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chocolate_Checkbox) ;
    boolean hasChocolate = chocolateCheckBox.isChecked();

    /**
     * Calculates the price of the order.
    */
    int price = calculatePrice(hasWhippedCream, hasChocolate);

    /**
     * Displays the price Message of the order.
     */
    String priceMessage = createOrderSummary(price, hasWhippedCream, hasChocolate, name);

    //Sends an email of order summary after calculating the order value
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    String email = "YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS"; // Ex. naveen@gmail.com

    intent.setType("plain/text");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{email});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Just Java Order for" + name);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, priceMessage);

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email...")); 
    }
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thanks, this did work, what has gone wrong with my existing code ? I followed it from the tutor, but didn't work..!!